# Can DITA Profile Attributes be used to `exclude` content from export

Tags: xml, dita, oxygenxml, dita-ot

In the [DITA examples](https://docs.oasis-open.org/dita/v1.2/os/spec/archSpec/condproc.html) I've seen, profiling attributes have only been used to specify which content to `include` in the the publishing process (such as `audience=novice`).

But, since there are such a small group of elements that I wish to exclude from my export, I wish to only tag elements that should be excluded from the export.

An example of this would be `deny=commercial`, so I can choose to instruct DITA-OT to produce a shareable version of a document that includes all content **except** the handful of items that are tagged as commercially sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

I should have googled further.  I've now found an [example](https://docs.oasis-open.org/dita/dita/v1.3/os/part2-tech-content/langRef/ditaval/ditaval-val.html) of how to support this.

Within the model in the question, I would define an `audience` value of `deny-commercial`, then for an export that omits commercially sensitive data it would `exclude` `audience:deny-commercial`.

Note: I've prepended `deny` since specifying `audience:commercial` would be counter-intuitive when the intention is to tag items to be excluded.

[image: screenshot with sample of excluding a group]